# How to fix progressive indents in Rmarkdown manual tables?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am adding multiple manual tables to an Rmarkdown document. When I knit to HTML, each subsequent table after the first is indented by a progressively increasing amount. I a) don't understand why this is happening and b) would very much like it to not be happening.

I have tried inputting the tables as pure Rmarkdown text using the pipes framework from Pandoc. I have tried putting pipe-frame Pandoc tables in R chunks. Currently I'm using the `tribble` function from the tidyverse package and formatting via `kable` and `kable_styling`.

```
---
title: "2.2 EICRP Codebook"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_notebook: default
  word_document: default
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

if (!require(pacman)) {
     install.packages("pacman", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
     require(pacman)
}

p_load(here, 
       knitr, 
       kableExtra,
       tidyverse)

rm(list = ls())
```

A.1. How would you characterize your environmental behavior and actions on a scale of 1 to 5?

Some text.

```
tribble(
  ~"QA01", ~"Value", ~"Label", 
  "01", "1", "Very Unsustainable", 
  "02", "2", "Unsustainable", 
  "03", "3", "Neither Sustainable nor Unsustainable", 
  "04", "4", "Sustainable", 
  "05", "5", "Very Sustainable"
) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

---

A.2. In the last two years, have you participated in the following (please tick all that apply)

Some text.

```
tribble(
  ~"QA02_01", ~"Value", ~"Label", 
  "01", "0", "No", 
  "02", "1", "Any Environmentally Sustainable Action"
) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()

tribble(
  ~"QA02_02", ~"Value", ~"Label", 
  "01", "0", "No", 
  "02", "1", "Environmental Activism"
) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()

tribble(
  ~"QA02_03", ~"Value", ~"Label", 
  "01", "0", "No", 
  "02", "1", "Neither"
) %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image: Apparently I'm not allowed to add images yet, but if you click here you'll see what I mean]

The tables in the second code block are formatted with an additional indent.

---

Update:

I've implemented a work-around using the `column_spec` function, but I'd still like to know why this is happening.